# JSF- render 2 values in one column in dataTable

Tags: java, jsf, xhtml

I have a dataTable in JSF and in one column i must render a date. To view in page for a specific format I use a convertDateTime. The problem is when validationDate is loaded this value it is not converted for my pattern. Only the first value (stampoperation), if it is loaded, is converted for my pattern.

```
<t:dataTable value="#{ProductBean.viewByid}"
             var="item" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2"
             width="100%" id="dtbl" headerClass="tableSotableHeader"
             preserveDataModel="false" 
             rowClasses="rowOdd,rowEven">
   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="State" />
      </f:facet>
   </h:column>
   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
         <h:outputText value="Data start" />
      </f:facet>
      **<h:outputText value="#{item.stampoperation}" rendered="#{item.status!=15}" >
         <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{UIBean.tz}" type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm"/>
      </h:outputText>
      <h:outputText  value="#{item.validDate}" rendered="#{item.status==15}">
         <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{UIBean.tz}" type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm"/>
      </h:outputText>**
   </h:column>
</t:dataTable>
```

Comment: Solved: I put values in a panel Group. <t:panelGroup id="x1"><h:outputText value="#{item.stampoperation}" rendered="#{item.status!=15}" >
         <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{UIBean.tz}" type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm"/>
      </h:outputText>
      <h:outputText  value="#{item.validDate}" rendered="#{item.status==15}">
         <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{UIBean.tz}" type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm"/>
      </h:outputText></t:panelGroup>

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar issue like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

When you dynamically display some component, it should be wrapped in a panelGroup and that panelGroup should have rendered attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I put values in a panel Group

```
<t:panelGroup id="x1">                                                                <h:outputText value="#{item.stampoperation}" rendered="#{item.status!=15}" >
         <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{UIBean.tz}" type="date" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm"/>
      </h:outputText>
      <h:outputText  value="#{item.validDate}" rendered="#{item.status==15}">
         <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{UIBean.tz}" type="date"  pattern="dd.MM.yyyy, HH:mm"/>
       </h:outputText>                                                            </t:panelGroup>
```